# Date comparison in Javascript and SQLite

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, sencha-touch

I am trying to perform a date comparison.Following is the scenario.I am getting a response from web request in XML format and from that I am parsing a date value as 
"2014-07-15T09:23:08.378Z"(EST format).Now I am saving this into SQLite database using query

```
INSERT INTO table_name (dateValue) VALUES(DATETIME(?))",modifiedDate]
```

Later when trying to retrieve this save date value ,I am getting the result in the format "2014-07-02 09:23:08"(which is in DATETIME format from sqlite).Now I need to compare these two date formats (i.e "2014-07-15T09:23:08.378Z" and "2014-07-02 09:23:08").Please help me on this.Looking forward for a solution

Comment: Use Simpledateformat https://github.com/noahcooper/SimpleDateFormatJS

Comment: Obviously, you have to convert one or the other. Do you need to do the comparison in JavaScript or in SQLite?

Comment: Workaroung: Could it work comparing strings if you put "T" on the right position?

Answer (score 1):

The data you are getting after parsing the response from web server is in standard ISO format.

You can use library or write your own prototype for the conversion.Ex.

```
Date.prototype.toCustomISOString = function() {
  return this.getUTCFullYear() +
    '-' + test_pad( this.getUTCMonth() + 1 ) +
    '-' + test_pad( this.getUTCDate() ) +
    ' ' + test_pad( this.getUTCHours() ) +
    ':' + test_pad( this.getUTCMinutes() ) +
    ':' + test_pad( this.getUTCSeconds() ) 
};

function test_pad(number) {
  if ( number < 10 ) {
    return '0' + number;
  }
  return number;}
```

Now you have to compare the date present in below variable.

```
var date1 = new Date("2014-07-15T09:23:08.378Z").toCustomISOString();  

var date2 = new Date("2014-07-15 09:23:08");
```

You can easily compare these two date variable by checking equality (==) -> getDate() -> getTime().